# Converting HeavisideTheta[]s and Sign[]s functions to a single Piecewise[]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the product of some Heaviside functions or sign functions, a simple example could be:

```
HeavisideTheta[q^2 - 4]*Sign[q - 3]
```

Another slightly more complicated example, involving a quartic function could be:

```
HeavisideTheta[Sqrt[((q - 3)^2 - 10)^2 + 15] - 8]
```

Clearly the resulting function will be composed of many steps, so I would like to convert it to a piecewise function. For the example before, the result would be:

```
Piecewise[{{-1, q <= -2}, {0, -2 < q <= 2}, {-1, 2 <= q < 3}}, 1]
```

Except for (maybe) a zero measure set, for which I don't care. Many times the variable appears quadratically or quartically inside the functions, so solving to find the zero may be non trivial, but it can always be done exactly by Solve[] or Reduce[].

I need to repeat this procedure a lot of times, so I would like to automate the procedure... Is there a way to teach Mathematica how to do it?

Comment: Are all your functions quadratic?

Comment: No, they are not. Some of them are quartic, however it's possibile to find the zeroes of each one analytically.

Comment: Please edit your question with a non quadratic one.

Comment: Done. Actually it's not a quartic strictly speaking, but while solving the equation in order to find the zeroes, you get a quartic and so you get 4 solutions in the end.

Answer (score 7):

We can use `PiecewiseExpand`.

```
ToPiecewise[f_] := PiecewiseExpand[f /. {
  (HeavisideTheta | UnitStep)[x_] :> Piecewise[{{1, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}], 
  Sign[x_] :> Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {0, x == 0}, {-1, x < 0}}]
}]
```

On your examples:

```
ToPiecewise[HeavisideTheta[q^2 - 4]*Sign[q - 3]]
(* Piecewise[{{-1, 2 <= q < 3 || q <= -2}, {1, q > 3}}, 0] *)

ToPiecewise[HeavisideTheta[Sqrt[((q - 3)^2 - 10)^2 + 15] - 8]]
(* Piecewise[{{1, Sqrt[15 + (-10 + (-3 + q)^2)^2] >= 8}}, 0] *)
```

We can also incorperate `Reduce` if we supply a variable:

```
ToPiecewise[f_, z_] := PiecewiseExpand[f /. {
  (HeavisideTheta | UnitStep)[x_] :> Piecewise[{{1, Reduce[x >= 0, z, Reals]}, {0, Reduce[x < 0, z, Reals]}}], 
  Sign[x_] :> Piecewise[{{1, Reduce[x > 0, z, Reals]}, {0, Reduce[x == 0, z, Reals]}, {-1, Reduce[x < 0, z, Reals]}}]
}]
```

Your example:

```
ToPiecewise[HeavisideTheta[Sqrt[((q - 3)^2 - 10)^2 + 15] - 8], q]
(* Piecewise[{{1, 3 - Sqrt[3] <= q <=  3 + Sqrt[3] || q >= 3 + Sqrt[17] || q <= 3 - Sqrt[17]}}, 0] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try solving for the arguments `HeavisideTheta` and Sign and combine the roots. Since they are in product form root of individual function will also be a root.

Aleternatively you can produce a data set and find the `Interpolation` like

```
data = Table[{q, HeavisideTheta[q^2 - 4]*Sign[q - 3]}, {q, -4, 4, .1}];
f = Interpolation[data];
Plot[f[x], {x, -4, 4}]
FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 3}]
```

You can't use `Solve` because your function, due to the `HeavisideTheta` will be 0 over a region which means infinite solution. So only significant solution will come from the argument of `Sign` which will give the point where your function cut the zero axis (provided `HeavisideTheta` is not zero there). `FindRoot` would be more efficient choice but you have to be careful about the initial value, or else you may be lost forever.

Answer (score 1):

I do admit that it's pretty ugly but here is an approach:

```
expr[q_] := HeavisideTheta[q^2 - 4]*Sign[q - 3]
bounds = Sort@Flatten[expr[q] /. 
  Times[a_, b_] :> {a, b} /. 
  {HeavisideTheta[a_] :> Re /@ N@Solve[a == 0, First@Variables@a][[All, 1, 2]], 
   Sign[Plus[a_, b_]] :> Abs@a, Sign[_] :> 0}];
b = Flatten[{{Prepend[{bounds[[1]]}, x]}, 
  Riffle[bounds[[#]], x] & /@ 
    Partition[Delete[Delete[Flatten[{#, #} & /@ Range@Length@bounds], -1], 1], 2]}, 1];
lb = LessEqual @@@ b;
oob = With[{l = Cases[#, _?NumberQ]}, If[Length@l < 2, Flatten@{2*l, l}, l]] &;
value = With[{q = #}, expr[q]] & /@ (RandomReal[#] & /@ oob /@ b);

Show@{
  Plot[expr@x, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dotted, Thick}],
  Plot[Piecewise[{#1, #2} & @@@ Thread[{value, lb}], 
    HeavisideTheta@Last@bounds], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With

```
expr[q_] := HeavisideTheta[Sqrt[((q - 3)^2 - 10)^2 + 15] - 8]*Sign[-3 + q];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]